# Trouble with Codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in my codeigniter application. But i got stucked. http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/ This is the tutorial i followed.
My controller

```
public function index() { 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url().'adminroles/';
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->M_admin_roles->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 20;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->M_admin_roles->
    fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data = array();
    $data['view_file'] = 'v_listRoles';
    echo Modules::run($this->template, $data);

}
```

My model

```
 public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $query = $this->db->get("roles");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all("roles");
 }
```

Iam rendering the view simply as

```
<p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

But shows error in view file. Error is "Undefined variable: links". What Iam doing wrong here?Is there anything to add as additionanal. Iam using HMVC Codeigniter. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: At the end of your index method you set `$data` to an empty array. So nothing will be in your view, remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

You have written

`<p><?php echo $links; ?></p>` in your view file,

but you have to write the following code in your view file

echo $this->pagination->create_links();

Answer (score 0):

You are initialize $data on wrong place.

Try this -

`public function index() { 
    $data = array();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url().'adminroles/';
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->M_admin_roles->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 20;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->M_admin_roles->
    fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links(); 
    $data['view_file'] = 'v_listRoles';
    echo Modules::run($this->template, $data);
}`

Comment: Thanks for the code.I have given everything as u said. still pagination is not working. in the first page itself all data is displayed